# conditional vectorized matching to named list of vectors

Tags: r

I have a named list of vectors, y. The names of the list correspond to the values of variable, x. I need to return the value of the vector in y that matches the value of x at position i. For example, if x == "b" at index 25, I expect to return the 25th value of the "b" vector contained in the list y.

This is my current solution:

```
x <- sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace = T)

y <- list("a"=rnorm(100), "b"=rnorm(100), "c"=rnorm(100))

i <- match(x, names(y))
m <- sapply(i, function(i) {out <- rep(0,3); out[i] <- 1; out})

final <- apply(t(m) * do.call(cbind, y), 1, sum)
```

I am hoping for something more idiomatic. As part of the solution, the answer handle cases where values in x do not appear in the names of y.

The real world use case I am trying to solve is the case where I have several segmented model predictions applied to the entire population that I need to assign to their appropriate segment.

**EDIT**
Also, trying to avoid the clunky usage of `ifelse`. Since the names are known, I shouldn't have to specify them manually.

Comment: Maybe something like this `final <- sapply(seq_along(x),function(i) y[[x[i]]][i])`. Basically loops through `x` and gets the corresponding values. You can make it into a vector using `as.numeric(as.character(final))`. The `NULL` will get replaced by `NA`.

Comment: do.call(cbind, y)[cbind(1:100, i)]

Comment: @Khashaa, you just blew my mind. Add that as an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using matrix subsetting with 2-dimensional indices, you could simply do

```
do.call(cbind, y)[cbind(1:length(i), i)]
```